# Formula to show unselected mutl-select picklist values in a separate field

Tags: formula

I'm trying to create a formula that will evaluate my Program_Type__c field on an opportunity screen and if that field is equal to "Accessories", it will then evaluate a multi-select picklist and if the picklist does not contain specific picks, it will display those as Paperwork Needed.  Now I completely know this formula is incorrect, but maybe this will help you decipher what i'm talking about.  Please help!  I have rewritten this formula 1000 times and cannot get the information I need.

My overall goal is to show the unselected picklist values in a field.

```
IF  
(ISPICKVAL(Program_Type__c , "Accessories")   
(!INCLUDES (Paperwork_Completed1__c, "Bank and Trade Info" ), "Bank and Trade Info" + BR() , NULL) +   
(!INCLUDES (Paperwork_Completed1__c, "Business License" ), "Business License" + BR() , NULL) +   
(!INCLUDES (Paperwork_Completed1__c, "Copy of Driver's License" ), "Copy of Driver's License" + BR() , NULL) +  
(!INCLUDES (Paperwork_Completed1__c, "Copy of Voided Check" ), "Copy of Voided Check" + BR() , NULL) +   
(!INCLUDES (Paperwork_Completed1__c, "Credit Card/Debit Card Auth" ), "Credit Card/Debit Card Auth" + BR() , NULL) +   
(!INCLUDES (Paperwork_Completed1__c, "Personal Guaranty" ), "Personal Guaranty" + BR() , NULL) +   
(!INCLUDES (Paperwork_Completed1__c, "Req. for Taxpayer ID Number and Cert" ), "Req. for Taxpayer ID Number and Cert" + BR() , NULL) +   
(!INCLUDES (Paperwork_Completed1__c, "Terms and Conditions" ), "Terms and Conditions" + BR() , NULL))
```

Comment: It was as if the CASE() function was tailor made for your situation. http://blogs.salesforce.com/blogs/2006/02/formula_tip_usi.html

Answer (score 1):

The formula you've given us is a good start, with a few required edits:

- you need a comma after `ISPICKVAL(Program_Type__c , "Accessories")`
- each of the picklist values you check for will have its own `IF` statement
- each of the strings that you're concatenating should be `''` if it's not included, instead of `NULL`
- you need an else clause at the end: `''`

  `IF

  (ISPICKVAL(Program_Type__c , "Accessories"),

  (IF(!INCLUDES (Paperwork_Completed1__c, "Bank and Trade Info" ), "Bank and Trade Info" + BR() , '')) +  ... + ...,
  '')`